# How to create a 75% confidence set for two random draws from a distribution taking values $\theta - 1$ and $\theta + 1$ with probability a half each?

Tags: confidence-interval

I read an older paper on likelihood principles recently by James Berger and inside they demonstrate an example involving confidence sets. What confuses me is how they specifically created a confidence set. To be exact, suppose we take two random draws $X_1, X_2$ from a discrete distribution $f(X|\theta)$ in which the random variable $X$ takes two values $\theta-1$ and $\theta+1$, each with probability $\frac{1}{2}$. The unknown parameter $\theta$ is in the range $-\infty < \theta < \infty$. Then they claim that:

$$
\hat{\theta}=
\begin{cases}
(X_1 + X_2)/2, & \text{if } X_1 \neq X_2\\
X_1-1, & \text{if } X_1 = X_2
\end{cases}
$$

defined a 75% confidence set for $\theta$.

I am not really sure how they were able to create the above interval. Can anyone shed some light? thanks.

Comment: I am almost sure that this question is a duplicate of one that has been asked and answered before, but a cursory search has not found it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, what is the probability that $X_1 \ne X_2$?  This is obviously analogous to the probability of flipping a fair coin twice and observing one head and one tail; i.e., $$\Pr[X_1 \ne X_2] = 1/2.$$  Then we see that $$\Pr[\hat \theta = \theta \mid \theta] = 1 \Pr[X_1 \ne X_2] + (1/2) \Pr[X_1 = X_2] = 0.75,$$ because with probability $1$, we know $\hat \theta = \theta$ when $X_1 \ne X_2$; and with probability $1/2$, we randomly choose the correct value between the equally likely possibilities that $\theta = X_1 - 1$ or $\theta = X_1 + 1$.  Consequently, the estimator $\hat\theta$ is, on average, correct $75\%$ of the time.

---

It's worth remarking that $\hat \theta$ is not an interval.  It is a *point* estimator.  But a singleton is still a set.

Comment: Can you share why you are conditioning on $\theta$?